# debugging in netbeans not working

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, tomcat6

I've a java project configured in netbeans 7.0.1 with tomcat 6.0. 
When I try to debug it , the project starts but i'm not able to connect to tomcat. The browser shows the busy icon and there is no errors in tomcat console. When I click on the stop debug button it gives the login page immediately. In short debugging is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have run into this before navigate to the Window > Debugging > Breakpoints and remove all breakpoints there is probably a hidden one that is preventing the login page from showing up.
[image]

Comment: that was the reason :) . One break point was stopping to see the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the NB's cache could help fixing this issue too.